# can we include build date and version in log4j info

Tags: java, logging, java-8, log4j

I would like to include build information (build version, date) in log statements.  Can this be done?  I'm using log4j in a Java 8 application.

Comment: Have the build server save the info to a property file which goes in the artifact.  Read file at runtime. Log as needed.  You most likely really need the git commit hash

Answer (score 2):

You can include the build date and version in your log statements.

For achieving this you have use two things

1. Get the build date and version dynamically or from a file
2. Update the logging pattern

Build plugin configuration : If you are using Spring Boot, your pom.xml should have

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-info</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Accessing Build Properties : After configuring your spring-boot-maven-plugin and building your application, you can access information about your application's build through BuildProperties object.

```
@Autowired
BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

Get the values

```
buildProperties.getName(); // Artifact's name from the pom.xml file    
buildProperties.getVersion(); // Artifact version    
buildProperties.getTime(); // Date and Time of the build    
buildProperties.getArtifact(); // Artifact ID from the pom file    
buildProperties.getGroup(); // Group ID from the pom file
```

Add the values using ThreadContext or MDC

```
MDC.put("build_date", buildProperties.getTime());
MDC.put("build_version", buildProperties.getVersion());
```

Update the logging pattern: Sample pattern

#Note the %X{userName} - this is how you fetch data from Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC)

```
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %-4r [%t] %5p %c %x - %m - %X{build_date} - %X{build_version}%n
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html). You could store the build date with something like the following:

```java
org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.put("buildDate", "01/01/1970");
```

Then use it in your log4j configuration with something like this:

```
<File name="Application" fileName="application.log">
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] $${ctx:buildDate} %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</File>
```

Same with the version. In my example I have hardcoded the value for the date, but you could retrieve it from a config file or an environment variable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring you can also do Spring Boot Lookup https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup

1. you have a pom.xml, lets say you want to log project.version from log4j

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyx</groupId>
    <artifactId>cpf-orchestration</artifactId>
    <version>Oct27_test1</version>
    <name>cpf</name>
    ...
```

2. Add this dependency

```xml
       <!-- Require for log4j to log spring properties -> ${spring:x} -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
           <version>2.16.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

3. your application.properties, reference the property

```
application-version=@project.version@
```

4. update your log4j2-spring.xml

```xml
        <Property name="SPLUNK_PATTERN"
                  value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}{America/Los_Angeles} | %logger:%M()| version:${spring:application-version} | msg=%m | %throwable{20}"/>
```